# Size to up animation for widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

In Flutter you suppose I have a simple `Container` and I would like to change the size of that to up, for example in this simple screenshot I want to change top container in section `1` to up to have a top container in section `2`
and top container in section `1` should behave only `100.0` after size to up

container `B` in section `1` and section `2` are in the same axis without change position when container `A` will be resized to up

[image]

for example, this is what I want to have

[image]

I'm not sure with which one animation I can have this feature

this code work, but this is not what I want to have.

i want to have draggable bottom sheet with changing border radius when bottom sheet arrived to top of screen like with pastes sample video screen and fade0n/out widget inside `appbar` which that inside top of bottom sheet, which that visible when bottom sheet arrived top or hide when bottom sheet don't have maximum size

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()=>runApp(SizeUp());

class SizeUp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'test',
      home: SizeUpAnim(),
    );
  }
}

class SizeUpAnim extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>_SizeUpAnim();
}

class _SizeUpAnim extends State with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  // ignore: constant_identifier_names
  static const _PANEL_HEADER_HEIGHT = 32.0;
  bool get _isPanelVisible {
    final AnimationStatus status = _controller.status;
    return status == AnimationStatus.completed ||
        status == AnimationStatus.forward;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller =  AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100), value: 1.0, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:  AppBar(
        elevation: 8.0,
        title:  const Text("Step4"),
        leading:  IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _controller.fling(velocity: _isPanelVisible ? -1.0 : 1.0);
          },
          icon:  AnimatedIcon(
            icon: AnimatedIcons.close_menu,
            progress: _controller.view,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: _buildStack,
            ),
          ),
          Text('aaa'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  Animation<RelativeRect> _getPanelAnimation(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    final double height = constraints.biggest.height;
    final double top = height - _PANEL_HEADER_HEIGHT;
    const double bottom = -_PANEL_HEADER_HEIGHT;
    return  RelativeRectTween(
      begin:  RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0.0, top, 0.0, bottom),
      end:  const RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    ).animate( CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.linear));
  }

  Widget _buildStack(BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    final Animation<RelativeRect> animation = _getPanelAnimation(constraints);
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return  Container(
      color: theme.primaryColor,
      child:  Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
           const Center(
            child:  Text("base"),
          ),
           PositionedTransition(
            rect: animation,
            child:  Material(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(16.0)),
              elevation: 12.0,
              child:  Container(
                height: _PANEL_HEADER_HEIGHT,
                child:  const Center(child:  Text("panel")),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are these containers placed? Containers aa in rows wrapped in column or containers ab in column wrapped in row... it is really hard to help without a code!!

Comment: @delmin containers are placed inside `Column`s

Comment: Is the header size fixed or can it be fixed for the sake of simplicity?

Comment: @RémiRousselet size of header is fixed, in fact that's `AppBar` which that visible when bottom sheet arrived top of screen. like with screen video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isLong = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('hey'),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setImages();
                setState(() {
                  isLong = !isLong;
                });
              },
              child: Text(isLong ? 'long' : 'short'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _onPressed,
              child: Text('open'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onPressed() {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(TransparentRoute(builder: (context) => NewWidget(images)));
  }

  List<String> images = List.generate(
    5,
    (_) => 'http://placeimg.com/100/100/any',
  );

  void setImages() {
    images = List.generate(
      isLong ? 5 : 25,
      (_) => 'http://placeimg.com/100/100/any',
    );
  }
}

class NewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewWidget(this.images, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> images;
  @override
  _NewWidgetState createState() => _NewWidgetState();
}

class _NewWidgetState extends State<NewWidget> {
  bool isBig = false;
  bool isStack = false;
  bool isBounsing = true;
  final double topOffset = 200;
  final double miniHandleHeigh = 30;
  double safeAreaPadding = 0;
  double startBigAnimationOffset;
  double startStickyOffset;
  double backgroundHeight = 0;
  double get savedAppBarHeigh => safeAreaPadding + kToolbarHeight;

  final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _afterLayout(_) {
    var media = MediaQuery.of(context);
    safeAreaPadding = media.padding.top;
    startBigAnimationOffset = topOffset - savedAppBarHeigh;
    startStickyOffset = startBigAnimationOffset + 20;
    backgroundHeight = media.size.height - miniHandleHeigh - topOffset;

    var canScroll = !_isImageSizeBiggerThenBottomSheetSize(
      media.size.width,
      media.size.height,
    );

    controller.addListener(
      canScroll ? withoutScrolling : withScrolling,
    );
  }

  void withoutScrolling() {
    var offset = controller.offset;
    if (offset < 0) {
      goOut();
    } else {
      controller.animateTo(
        0,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
      );
    }
  }

  void withScrolling() {
    var offset = controller.offset;

    if (offset < 0) {
      goOut();
    } else if (offset < startBigAnimationOffset && isBig) {
      setState(() {
        isBig = false;
      });
    } else if (offset > startBigAnimationOffset && !isBig) {
      setState(() {
        isBig = true;
      });
    } else if (offset > startStickyOffset && !isStack) {
      setState(() {
        isStack = true;
      });
    } else if (offset < startStickyOffset && isStack) {
      setState(() {
        isStack = false;
      });
    }

    if (offset < topOffset && !isBounsing) {
      setState(() => isBounsing = true);
    } else if (offset > topOffset && isBounsing) {
      setState(() => isBounsing = false);
    }
  }

  void goOut() {
    controller.dispose();
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  _isImageSizeBiggerThenBottomSheetSize(
    double screenWidth,
    double screenHeight,
  ) {
    // padding: 10, 3 in row;
    print(screenHeight);

    var itemHeight = (screenWidth - 20) / 3;
        print(itemHeight);

    var gridMaxHeight = screenHeight - topOffset - miniHandleHeigh;
        print(gridMaxHeight);

    return (widget.images.length / 3).floor() * itemHeight > gridMaxHeight;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: isStack ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: backgroundHeight),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ListView(
            physics:
                isBounsing ? BouncingScrollPhysics() : ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            controller: controller,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                height: topOffset,
                child: TweenAnimationBuilder(
                    tween: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: isBig ? 1.0 : 0.0),
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black38,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                          ),
                          height: 5,
                          width: 60,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    builder: (_, number, child) {
                      return Container(
                        height: savedAppBarHeigh * number + miniHandleHeigh,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                              top: Radius.circular((1 - number) * 20)),
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        child: Opacity(opacity: 1 - number, child: child),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minHeight:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - savedAppBarHeigh),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: getGrid(),
              )
            ],
          ),
          if (isStack)
            _AppBar(
              title: 'Gallery',
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getGrid() {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: widget.images.map((url) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          ),
          child: Image(
            image: NetworkImage(url),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class _AppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const _AppBar({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final Color backgroundColor = Colors.white;
  final Color color = Colors.grey;
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 5,
      child: Container(
        height: kToolbarHeight + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
        color: backgroundColor,
        child: OverflowBox(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          maxHeight: 200,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: kToolbarHeight),
              child: AppBar(
                centerTitle: false,
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                  color: color, //change your color here
                ),
                primary: false,
                title: Text(
                  title,
                  style: TextStyle(color: color),
                ),
                elevation: 0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}

class TransparentRoute extends PageRoute<void> {
  TransparentRoute({
    @required this.builder,
    RouteSettings settings,
  })  : assert(builder != null),
        super(settings: settings, fullscreenDialog: false);

  final WidgetBuilder builder;

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => null;

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 350);

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    final result = builder(context);
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: Tween<Offset>(
          begin: const Offset(0, 1),
          end: Offset.zero,
        ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
          parent: animation,
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
        )),
        child: result,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot my friend, :) how about border radius? could you update your code like with video screen?

Comment: and there is another things, start of resizing of this pink container should be change when arrived under appBar and finished when arrived on top of screen, start of change height to expand when arrived under appbar and collapse when arrived under appbar too, like with video screen

Comment: I found out now, you updated your post, i test, and that what i want to have :)

Comment: how can i set elastic animation on opening `BottomSheet` in first time?

Comment: i found a little bit bug in that, when i clicked on `open` button` and after showing `bottomSheet` i can't scroll down to close

Comment: to set elastic animation you can add CurvedAnimation for TransparentRoute, I've added to the example code

Comment: Thanks for noticing bug, I'll try to solve it today or tomorrow morning.

Comment: i found another bug :) if you change count of listview items from 200 to for example 10, you can see container of this child doesn't have full height

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try this library, [sliding_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_sheet)

when you detect the expand status by controller, then you animate/enlarge the container A.

Comment: i see this library, `sliding_sheet` is not what i want to have